# Testing my ANTLR4 grammar with unit tests

Tags: antlr4

Is there a good/convenient way to test a ANTLR4 grammar vor the JavaScript target?

Currently I'm writing lots and lots of unit tests for input/output combinations (text files). I'm not quite sure if that's a good way. It is working until now but maybe there's a better way.

Comment: [SnippetsTest](https://github.com/grosenberg/SnippetsTest) is for Java. No reason why the basic approach could not be applied to Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Looks promising.

Comment: Hi @FabianDeitelhoff
, what test framework did you used? I'm currently trying to use Jest but I'm getting errors from the ANTLR4 runtime:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76686712/testing-antlr4-parser-in-javascript-with-jest