# Jest test of ANTLR4 parser fails to import antlr4 module (Cannot use import statement outside a module)

Tags: javascript, jestjs, antlr, antlr4, ts-jest

I implemented a parser in TypeScript/JavaScript with ANTLR4 and now I want to write unit tests for the parser.

However, when I try to import antlr4 into my test file I receive the following error:

```
....\node_modules\antlr4\dist\antlr4.node.mjs:1
 SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

> 1 | import antlr4 from 'antlr4';
    | ^
```

my test file so far - which is a mimimal example to produce the error:

```
import antlr4 from 'antlr4';

test('test_case', () => {
   const chars = new antlr4.InputStream("test");
});
```

Any idea how one has to configure jest to get rid of this error?

I'm using the newest versions of jest and antlr4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to configure Jest to handle ECMAScript modules (ES modules) properly.
you can install the babel-jest package as a dev dependency, which allows Jest to transform ES modules using Babel. Then Create a Babel configuration file named babel.config.js in the root of your project (if you don't have one already) and add the following

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```

then Update your Jest configuration in the jest.config.js file

```js
module.exports = {
  // Other Jest configuration options...
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
  },
}
```

This should let you use the import statement in your Jest test file. If you encounter any other issues related to Babel or Jest configuration, ensure that you have installed the necessary Babel plugins and presets, such as @babel/preset-env